# Calculating values from the same table but a different period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `readings` table with the following definition.

```
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |               Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('readings_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 type       | character varying(50)       |           | not null |
 device     | character varying(100)      |           | not null |
 value      | numeric                     |           | not null |
```

It has data such as:

```
 id |     created_at      |  type  | device | value
----+---------------------+--------+--------+-------
  1 | 2021-05-11 04:00:00 | weight | 1      |   100
  2 | 2021-05-10 03:00:00 | weight | 2      |   120
  3 | 2021-05-10 04:00:00 | weight | 1      |   120
  4 | 2021-05-10 03:00:00 | weight | 1      |   124
  5 | 2021-05-01 22:43:47 | weight | 1      |   130
  6 | 2021-05-01 15:00:48 | weight | 1      |   140
  7 | 2021-05-01 13:00:48 | weight | 2      |   160
```

**Desired Output**

Given a `device` and a `type`, I would like the max and min `value` from the past 7 days for each matched row (active row ignored). If there's nothing in the past 7 days, then it should be 0.

```
 id |     created_at      |  type  | device | value | min | max
----+---------------------+--------+--------+-------+-----+-----
  1 | 2021-05-11 03:09:47 | weight | 1      | 100   | 120 | 124
  3 | 2021-05-10 04:00:00 | weight | 1      | 120   | 124 | 124
  4 | 2021-05-10 03:00:00 | weight | 1      | 124   | 0   | 0
  5 | 2021-05-01 22:43:47 | weight | 1      | 130   | 140 | 140
  6 | 2021-05-01 15:00:48 | weight | 1      | 140   | 0   | 0
```

I have created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/petXUoJ4qXw2akki3yHkti/0).

Comment: By _"active row ignored"_, you mean take the past 7 days but not the current day ?

Comment: No, I mean, when we're looking at row with `id = 1`, then we look for 7 days before that row's `created_at`. That row's `value` should not be considered in the min/max. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lateral left join` for your requirement like below:

```
select 
t1.id,
t1.created_at,
t1.type,
t1.device,
t1.value,
min(coalesce(t2.value,0)),
max(coalesce(t2.value,0))
from 
readings t1 
left join lateral 
( select * 
 from readings 
 where id!=t1.id and created_at between t1.created_at- interval '7 day' and t1.created_at and device=t1.device and t1.type=type
) t2 on true
where t1.device='1'  -- Change the device 
and t1.type='weight'  -- Change the type 
group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by 1
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/petXUoJ4qXw2akki3yHkti/4)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the comments, here is your PSQL:

```
select readings.id, readings.type, readings.device, readings.created_at, readings.value, 
      min(COALESCE(m_readings.value,0)) min, max(COALESCE(m_readings.value,0)) max
  from readings LEFT JOIN readings m_readings
                       ON m_readings.type =readings.type
                      AND m_readings.device =readings.device
                      AND m_readings.id > readings.id
                      AND date( m_readings.created_at) between (date(readings.created_at)-7) and date(readings.created_at)
 group by readings.id, readings.type, readings.device, readings.created_at, readings.value
 order by readings.id;
```

Explanations: We make a `LEFT` junction between each records of `readings` and the others records of `readings` which are of the same `type` and `device` but **not the same `id`**, keeping only the last 7 days records. Then for each `type/device`we are grouping to get max and min `value`on this 7 days.

Comment: Using the code above, I don't get the expected result when filtering on `Id = 1 and type = 'weight'`, see [db-fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/petXUoJ4qXw2akki3yHkti/3).

Comment: hmm still doesn't seem to work when I add a `where` clause. Can you updated the query to show it with a where clause of `id = 1 and type = 'weight'` please.

Comment: Corrected, i 've seen your intent a little late  ^^

Answer (score 1):

You should be using window functions for this!

```
select r.*,
       max(value) over (partition by device, type
                        order by created_at
                        range between interval '7 day' preceding and interval '1 second' preceding
                       ),
       min(value) over (partition by device, type
                        order by created_at
                        range between interval '7 day' preceding and interval '1 second' preceding
                       )
from readings r;
```

The above returns `NULL` values when there are no values -- and that makes more sense to me than `0`.  But if you *really* want `0`, just use `COALESCE()`:

```
select r.*,
       coalesce(max(value) over (partition by device, type
                                 order by created_at
                                 range between interval '7 day' preceding and interval '1 second' preceding
                       ), 0),
       coalesce(min(value) over (partition by device, type
                                 order by created_at
                                 range between interval '7 day' preceding and interval '1 second' preceding
                       ), 0)
from readings r;
```

In addition to being more concise, this is easier to read and should have better performance than other methods.